# Count group of each Key Value pair in a list

Tags: c#

I am using below code to read data from text file separated by pipeline ('|') delimiter:

```
class Data
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

using(TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(TEXT_FILE_PATH + ReadFile + ".txt"))
{
    csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { FILE_DELIMETER });
    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

    List<Data> KeyValue = new List<Data>();
    while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields = csvReader.ReadFields();
        if (   fields[7] != ""
            && fields[8] != ""
            && fields[7] != string.Empty
            && fields[8] != string.Empty)
            KeyValue.Add(new Data { Key = fields[7], Value = fields[8] });
    }
}
```

Firstly, I am populating specific field of row into list with KeyValue Pair.
After, data is populated I want to calculate the count of each pair. The key value pair is repeating.

How should I do that?

Comment: Look for method `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`, it will simplify code.

Comment: So is it that you want to count groups that have the same Key AND the same Value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ. For example if you want to store the result in a dictionary where the key is the combination of key and value and the value is the count of duplicates:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, int> keyValueCounts = KeyValue
    .GroupBy(x => Tuple.Create(x.Key, x.Value))
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

> Will you please also help me in reading the data from Dictionary
>   object in an optimized way

If you for example wanted to enumerate all items in the list you could output the result so:

```
foreach (Data d in KeyValue)
{
    Tuple<string, string> keyval = Tuple.Create(d.Key, d.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Data:{0} Count:{1}", keyval, keyValueCounts[keyval]);
}
```

Comment: Will you please also help me in reading the data from Dictionary object in an optimized way

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform group by and then perform projection to select the count. Please find below code:

```
var countList = KeyValue.GroupBy(c=>c.Key).Select(g=> new { g.Key,g.Count()}.ToList();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that he wants to find out how often the combination of key **and** value appears.

Answer (score 1):

This will create list of distinct key-value pairs with the count of their appearance in the main list:

```
var resultList = KeyValue.GroupBy(p => new { p.Key, p.Value })
.Select(g => new{
    KeyValuePair = g.Key,
    Count = g.Count() }).ToList();
```